# Ubuntu 13.04 + touch screen: points, though doesn't click

Tags: 13.04, multi-touch, cursor, touchscreen, tap-to-click

Works well with nautilus and settings. 
Other places: I tap, cursor points, no further action.
Guide me. I need it. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue; the good news is that there's a patch to fix it -- see [(1)](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56578) and [(2)](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=78125). Follow the steps below (at your own risk) to apply the patch, compile the source, and install the patched packages:

1. Install the build dependencies for the source package
   `sudo apt-get build-dep xorg-server`
2. Download the *xorg-server* package
   `sudo apt-get source xorg-server`
3. `cd` to the directory created by the previous command
4. Download the patch, which can be found at [2](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=78125)
5. Apply the patch you just downloaded
   `patch -p0 < ~/Downloads/touch-fix.patch` (assuming the patch is in ~/Downloads)
6. Compile and generate the packages (.deb files)
   `debuild -b -us -uc`
7. Install the packages
   `sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb`
8. Restart your machine

I hope this helps.

(1) https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56578
(2) https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=78125

Comment: Still the same.